# Typescript for typical observer pattern

Tags: typescript, generics, observers

I'm trying to write typescript for a structure like observer pattern and I'm failing to achieve this. I think I'm almost done but for some reason I don't understand why the ts is complaining.

```
type OnChangeListener = (object: object, from: string, to: string) => void
type OnCreateListener = (object: object) => void

type ListenerTypes = {
    onChange: OnChangeListener,
    onCreate: OnCreateListener
}

type Listener<T extends keyof ListenerTypes> = ListenerTypes[T]

type Listeners = {
    onChange: OnChangeListener[],
    onCreate: OnCreateListener[]
}

class SomeClass {
    private listeners: Listeners = {
        onChange: [],
        onCreate: []
    }

    public create(object: object) {
        this.listeners.onCreate.forEach(listener => listener(object))
    }

    public change(object: object, from: string, to: string) {
        this.listeners.onChange.forEach(listener => listener(object, from, to))
    }

    public registerListener<T extends keyof ListenerTypes>(name: T, listener: Listener<T>): void
    {
        this.listeners[name].push(listener) // <-- here is a problem
        /*
Argument of type 'Listener<T>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OnCreateListener'.
  Type 'OnChangeListener | OnCreateListener' is not assignable to type 'OnCreateListener'.
    Type 'OnChangeListener' is not assignable to type 'OnCreateListener'
        */
    }
}

const someObject = new SomeClass()

someObject.registerListener("onChange", (o, from, to) => {}) // <-- this is ok
someObject.registerListener("onCreate", (o) => {}) // <-- this is ok
someObject.registerListener("onCreate",  (o, from, to) => {}) // <-- this error is ok, as the callback should be different
```

When I change the Listeners type to

```
type Listeners = {
    onChange: any[],
    onCreate: any[]
}
```

then register function works ok, but the trigger doesn't shows any type on the listener object in forEach as it's obvious. So the option there is casting what I don't like. What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the index type [examples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types) in the docs, it seems that generically indexing only works when the type of the object being indexed is itself part of the generic context of the function, as opposed to a specific object outside of it.

Inside the `registerListener` function, the type of `listener` in `this.listeners[name].push(listener)` is expected to be an intersection of `OnChangeListener` and `OnCreateListener` because it doesn't know what whether `name` will be `"onChange"` or `"onCreate"` and will thus only accept function signatures that are applicable to both. Typescript doesn't do the generic index magic unless the object type is generic as well.

Since `registerListener` *does* properly discriminate the listener signature that should be passed for the given key, I think the best solution is just to tell Typescript that the listener array you're accessing matches the listener passed.

```js
public registerListener<T extends keyof ListenerTypes>(name: T, listener: Listener<T>): void {
    (this.listeners[name] as Listener<T>[]).push(listener);  
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It looks like the best solution.